# How to read data from Arduino board to pc using C?

Tags: c, arduino, serial-port, usb

I found a tutorial for writing data to an Arduino board over here: https://salilkapur.wordpress.com/2013/03/08/communicating-with-arduino-using-c/

The code uses `file = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0","w+");`to open the port for the read/write operation and uses `fprintf` to write data to the device. But when I tried using `fscanf` to retrieve the data from the Arduino (I used `Serial.print` for writing the data back to the PC from the Arduino end, and the data  was formatted as `DEC`), it didn't work.

I am able to see the output using the serial monitor in the Arduino IDE but I am not able to view the output in my C program's output. Why isn't it working and what do I have to do to get it working?

The program was run in Ubuntu.

This is my C code that is supposed to run on the PC:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    char a=0;
    file = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0","w+");  
    int i = 0;
    if(file == -1)
        printf("error");
    for(i = 0 ; i < 3 ; i++)
    {
        fprintf(file,"C"); 
        fscanf(file, "%c", &a);
        printf("%c", a);
    }



    fclose(file);
 }
```

I also tried few variations like, using `%d` instead of `%c`, using `int` in place of char and using `fflush`. I don't know why it doesn't work. Could it be that my Arduino board doesn't work?

Note: it is supposed to give an output after every character input.

Comment: I suspect there might be a problem in your code.

Comment: Are you sure your arduino is at `/dev/ttyUSB0` ? Is the Serial Monitor opened in the Arduino IDE (You can't read/write when it is) ? Change `if(file == -1)` to `if(file == NULL)`. What is the arduino code ? By the way, you are trying to read a number (`DEC` in arduino) with a `%c` in your scanf, try with `%d`

Answer (score 1):

The reason you cannot read anything is that when you call

`file = fopen("/dev/ttyUSB0","w+");`

[the arduino is reset](https://tushev.org/articles/arduino/22), and it takes 1-2 seconds to boot. For some reason, the read hangs indefinetely.

Adding `sleep(2);` next to `fopen` will likely do the trick.

See how to [disable auto reset](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/DisablingAutoResetOnSerialConnection)